# How to implement two IBActions in UIButton without overlap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

I drag **2 IBActions** from a `UIButton`, one with touchDown event and second with drag Inside.

```
- (IBAction)clickButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Click Button");
}

- (IBAction)dragInsideButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Drag Button");
}
```

But when I drag inside, the touchDown action also gets fired.

How to disable touchDown event when dragInside.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess, make a BOOL and check in both the method and flip the action by : `-(void)removeTarget:action:`

Comment: Do you also want the reverse to happen -- that is, if touchDown is fired do you need dragInside not to happen if the user starts dragging? The only way to make this work is going to be with a slight delay at the beginning to wait and see if a drag starts. If that's not acceptable, then you'll have to go with a different design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have solved a problem like this with using drag Events

add events to your button in .xib file or programatically.

programmatically is:

```
[mybut addTarget:self action:@selector(dragBegan:withEvent: )
  forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [mybut addTarget:self action:@selector(dragMoving:withEvent: )
  forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [mybut addTarget:self action:@selector(dragEnded:withEvent: )
  forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside |
     UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

then defininitons of events are:

```
- (void) dragBegan: (UIButton *) c withEvent:ev
{
    NSLog(@"dragBegan......");
    count=NO;//bool Value to decide the Down Event
    c.tag=0;
  [self performSelector:@selector(DownSelected:) withObject:mybut afterDelay:0.1];
 //user must begin dragging in 0.1 second else touchDownEvent happens

}

- (void) dragMoving: (UIButton *) c withEvent:ev
{
    NSLog(@"dragMoving..............");
    c.tag++;
}

- (void) dragEnded: (UIButton *) c withEvent:ev
{
    NSLog(@"dragEnded..............");
    if (c.tag>0 && !count)
    {

        NSLog(@"make drag events");

    }

}



-(void)DownSelected:(UIButton *)c
{
    if (c.tag==0) {
        NSLog(@"DownEvent");
        count=YES;//count made Yes To interrupt drag event
    }

}
```

Comment: Clever way!But touchDown target become a touchUpInside event.

Answer (score 3):

This method is tested, and should do what I think you're trying to do. You can change the delay in the timer to get the effect you want. I had to connect 3 actions to the button to make this work -- the third action is a touchUp that resets the system to the starting condition.

```
@interface LastViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL touchedDown;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSTimer *downTimer;
@end

@implementation LastViewController 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.touchedDown = NO;
}

-(IBAction)clickDown:(id)sender {
    self.downTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.3 target:self selector:@selector(buttonAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(IBAction)dragInside:(id)sender {
    [self.downTimer invalidate];
    [self buttonAction:self];
}


-(void) buttonAction:(id) sender {
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[NSTimer class]]) {
        self.touchedDown = YES;
        NSLog(@"click down");
    }else{
        if (! self.touchedDown) {
             NSLog(@"Drag");
        }
    }
}

-(IBAction)touchUpAction:(id)sender {
    self.touchedDown = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Drag just work OK 1st time. click, drag again not work. What's I need to do next? I don't know how to control timer.

Comment: Did you implement the touchUpAction method (and connect it to the button)? It worked fine for me, on repeated click and drags.

Comment: Thanks Sir! My target touchDownAction.

Comment: Yes Sir! I need more time to test.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

`isClicked` is property of type BOOL. Set to `YES`.

```
- (IBAction)clickButton:(UIButton *)sender { //touch down
    if(isClick==YES){
       NSLog(@"Click Button");
       //do all your stuffs here
    }
    isClick=YES;
}

- (IBAction)dragInsideButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Drag Button");
    isClick=NO;
}
```

On top of this you can also implement `removeTarget:Action:`

*Which ever method gets called first set isClick=NO, I expect clickButton is called first in button action.*

Comment: Thanks!Click button button always fire first, I don't know how to control. I try both, but always 2 action fire.

Comment: i think all actions goes into invocation and once it is set you cant stop. Have yuo tried by `removeTarget:Action:`  I am new in ios, still learning, so excuse.

Comment: Thanks! If do like that, My touchDown event just fire when double click.

Comment: Sorry sir!Cant reply soon.In my bed time. Not OK yet.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure it will work but you can try

```
   - (IBAction)dragInsideButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [sender removeTarget:self forSelector:@selector(clickButton:) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got from [Two action methods for an UIButton; next track and seek forward:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926702/two-action-methods-for-an-uibutton-next-track-and-seek-forward)

## Change it As per your requirement.

Personally I'd just track the button's state with an integer on your view controller or within a button subclass. If you track what the button is doing you can control what each of the actions do. In your .h file put in some stuff like this:

```
enum {
    MyButtonScanning,
    MyButtonStalling,
    MyButtonIdle
};



@interface YourClass : UIViewController {
    NSInteger buttonModeAt;
}
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger buttonModeAt;
-(IBAction)buttonPushedDown:(id)sender;
-(void)tryScanForward:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonReleasedOutside:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonReleasedInside:(id)sender;
@end
```

And then in your .m file throw in some of this stuff:

```
@implementation YourClass
///in your .m file
@synthesize buttonModeAt;


///link this to your button's touch down
-(IBAction)buttonPushedDown:(id)sender {
    buttonModeAt = MyButtonStalling;
    [self performSelector:@selector(tryScanForward:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}

-(void)tryScanForward:(id)sender {
    if (buttonModeAt == MyButtonStalling) {
        ///the button was not released so let's start scanning
        buttonModeAt = MyButtonScanning;
        
        ////your actual scanning code or a call to it can go here
        [self startScanForward];
    }
}

////you will link this to the button's touch up outside
-(IBAction)buttonReleasedOutside:(id)sender {
    if (buttonModeAt == MyButtonScanning) {
        ///they released the button and stopped scanning forward
        [self stopScanForward];
    } else if (buttonModeAt == MyButtonStalling) {
        ///they released the button before the delay period finished
        ///but it was outside, so we do nothing
    }
    
    self.buttonModeAt = MyButtonIdle;
}

////you will link this to the button's touch up inside
-(IBAction)buttonReleasedInside:(id)sender {
    if (buttonModeAt == MyButtonScanning) {
        ///they released the button and stopped scanning forward
        [self stopScanForward];
    } else if (buttonModeAt == MyButtonStalling) {
        ///they released the button before the delay period finished so we skip forward
        [self skipForward];
    }
    
    self.buttonModeAt = MyButtonIdle;
    
}
```

After that just link the button's actions to what I've noted in the comments before the IBactions. I haven't tested this but it should work.